# How to load all symbols from shared library on start up?

Tags: c, linux, optimization, shared-libraries, glibc

Good day!
I have a fork-on-connect daemon. After profiling it with perf tool, I found out that function "do_lookup_x" consume lot's of CPU time. All the function calls for shared-libraries functions are after fork.

Is there any way to lookup all symbols before fork?

Comment: Have you tried `export LD_BIND_NOW=1` ? Set such environment variable then execute your program. See here: http://www.naval-acad.bg/HOWTO/GCC-HOWTO-7.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the environment variable `LD_BIND_NOW` should help achieving just that.

Set it with

`export LD_BIND_NOW=1`

then execute your program.

Excerpt:

> ELF platforms (Linux, Solaris, FreeBSD, HP-UX, IRIX, etc.) support
>   lazy binding of procedure addresses, which is an optimization that
>   yields better performance overall but a genuine problem for
>   applications that need uniform performance after startup (eg: trading
>   systems.) When an ELF application starts up, the loader (by default)
>   initializes the Procedure Linkage Table (PLT) with a bunch of fix-up
>   code that'll be run on the first invocation of each function.  On the
>   fix-up call, the function's position within the virtual address space
>   is looked up and placed into the PLT so that future invocations of the
>   function won't need to be looked up again.

The possible solutions:

> If you care about latency after startup, there's a few things you can
>   do:
>
> ```
> Have a "warmup phase" of your application that does a dlsym() lookup on every function;
> Use static libraries instead of shared libraries;
> Set LD_BIND_NOW=1 and force the loader to do the PLT fixups at startup;
> Use the "-z now" option on your linker (if you have it available).
> ```

Please see [here](http://badassdev.com/articles/2009/4/26/ld_bind_now-a-quick-cure-for-your-application-jitters.html) for the full article and [here](http://www.naval-acad.bg/HOWTO/GCC-HOWTO-7.html) for further info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information! I will try it. And anyway it was very interesting to read.